# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. error

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist

I got an error,
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. 
Now I am making iPhone app by swift.
I added several codes to Info.plist of my app, I deleted these codes.
But when I wanna open Info.plist of my app, this error happen.I do not know why because I deleted all codes which I added.And I think format is really fixed.
My Info.plist is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've duplicated key in the info.plist file, remove the following key in the beginning

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
```

and it will resolve the issue.

Comment: @Idindu give me error App/Info.plist': The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>twitterkit-X32etXSRAmuYhCboKPJWq8meM</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
   </array>
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>twitter</string>
  <string>twitterauth</string>
 </array>

Answer (score 1):

Try something below:

```
Right click on Info.plist -> Source Code -> Discard Change
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Building flutter project , and the problem was missing `<string>` for key   **io.flutter.embedded_views_preview**  adding  `<string></string>` fixed my issue , i didn't update the info.plist though it was as created by flutter , hope this will help someone using flutter